# Plot defaults to flat line on zero when I set ylim matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code for a plot a signal using matplotlib:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
plt.plot(df_and100['mod_time(second)'], df_and100['axy'])
plt.xlim(2875, 3100)
plt.show()
```

This results in the following graph[image: Signal using xlim only]

When I try to set the ylim I use the similar logic for xlim. The code is as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
plt.plot(df_and100['mod_time(second)'], df_and100['axy'])
plt.xlim(2875, 3100)
plt.ylim(-1,2)
plt.show()
```

The results in the following graph:
[image: Signal using xlim and ylim]

Hence clearly I am using ylim incorrectly. Can someone please help me plot the graph setting x lim and ylim correctly?
My goal is to simply plot graph 1 with restricted ylim values so that my signal is magnified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ylim` correctly. It's just that your data lies between `[-1 * 1e-18; 2 * 1e-18]`, not `[-1; 2]`. Hence you are seeing it all flattened.

You can see that in the top left corner of your first graph.